Budget alert schema differences
I am setting budget for each subscription and have set alerts to notify the action group which then calls a logic app workflow.
The action group has Enable the common alert schema. set to No. When I send a test payload using the Test action group button I receive a different schema than the one actually sent when budget threshold is hit.
What is the cause of this discrepancy?
Payload received when testing action group
{
  "schemaId": "AIP Budget Notification",
  "data": {
    "SubscriptionName": "test-subscription",
    "SubscriptionId": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
    "EnrollmentNumber": "",
    "DepartmentName": "test-budgetDepartmentName",
    "AccountName": "test-budgetAccountName",
    "BillingAccountId": "",
    "BillingProfileId": "",
    "InvoiceSectionId": "",
    "ResourceGroup": "test-RG",
    "SpendingAmount": "1111.32",
    "BudgetStartDate": "2024-11-05T20:00:44.628Z",
    "Budget": "10000",
    "Unit": "USD",
    "BudgetCreator": "email@domain.com",
    "BudgetName": "test-budgetName",
    "BudgetType": "Cost",
    "NotificationThresholdAmount": "8000.0"
  }
}

Actual payload received when budget alert is triggered
{
  "schemaId": "AIP Budget Notification",
  "data": {
    "BillingProfileName": "",
    "InvoiceSectionName": "",
    "EvaluatedAmount": "552.03",
    "BudgetThreshold": "550.0",
    "AlertGenerationTime": "November 30, 2024 12:55PM",
    "ForecastedTotalForPeriod": null,
    "TenantId": "<redacted>",
    "BudgetId": "<redacted>",
    "Scope": "<redacted>",
    "AlertId": "<redacted>",
    "ManagementGroupName": "",
    "ForecastedAmount": null,
    "ForecastedDate": null,
    "ForecastedPercentage": null,
    "SubscriptionName": "<redacted>",
    "SubscriptionId": "<redacted>",
    "EnrollmentNumber": "",
    "EnrollmentName": null,
    "DepartmentName": "",
    "AccountName": "",
    "BillingAccountId": "",
    "BillingProfileId": "",
    "InvoiceSectionId": "",
    "ResourceGroup": "",
    "BudgetStartDate": "2024-11-01",
    "Unit": "USD",
    "BudgetCreator": "",
    "BudgetName": "20241104212653417",
    "BudgetType": "Cost",
    "NotificationThresholdAmount": "550.00"
  }
}


Are you still facing the issue. @prinkpan

@Jahnavi, yes, although I have made changes to match the schema that I receive but would still be nice to know why the difference and any documentation showing the schema that I am receiving. Thank you.

Have you checked the below one. @prinkpan


What is the cause of this discrepancy?

According to this MSDoc,

Budget alerts notify us when spending, based on usage or cost, reaches or exceeds the amount defined in the alert condition of the budget.

Budget alerts for cost management can be set by visiting Subscriptions >> Cost Management >> Budgets as shown below which you already did.
Also, you can visit the same path for adding cost alerts by adding the specific threshold according to your requirements and trigger it.

The discrepancy is by default with the Azure cost management alert schema implementation. It means that there are schema differences for budgets and alerts in Azure.
The properties and values used to define budgets and alerts are different. For example, if we take the budget schema that contains properties like amount and timePeriod, when it comes to the alert schema, it has properties such as threshold and actions.
The relevant information is detailed in this Blog.
The main cause of discrepancy is, if a budget alert has been triggered, Azure generates the payload based on real-time data from the subscription and budget costs configuration. It leads to this conflict when comparing the test and actual payloads.
You can somehow avoid this discrepancy by setting
Enable the common alert schema to yes. Setting this to yes maintains the schema consistency without changing anything between the actual and test payload when triggered as shown below.


Thank you for the answer, Jahnavi. Strangely there is no Microsoft official documentation anywhere that shows the schema that we're receiving when Enable common alert schema is set to No. As of now we've just kept it as it is and changed the schema in logicapp to the actual we receive. We also checked by setting it to Yes we receive this schema.

According to its functionality, by default it is set to No and clearly seen in the portal. @prinkpan
